# jQuery not loaded from src in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I have recently got stuck in the following situation.
I have a script which works perfectly in FF and GC,but not in IE10.
The IE is not loading the jQuery src files,so therefore it triggers the error '$' is undefined.The loading part looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/jquery.jqplot.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/RequestCenter/modules/resources/dist/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
```

my function is simple:
$(document).ready(function() { ....  });

so,the IE10 doesn't load the jQuery and triggers the error on this line.
Any ideas how to find a work around would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you look in the network tab, what's the loading error? Does it try to load the correct file?

Comment: In the network tab the result is 304.It tries to load the correct file.In the response body is the file content.In the Initiator Tab:This download occurred as a speculative download during HTML preparsing. The Response Headers: Key Value
Response HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
ETag W/"268381-1364326058000"
Content-Type text/javascript
Content-Length 268381
Last-Modified Tue, 26 Mar 2013 19:27:38 GMT

Answer (score 0):

It might be a browser mode or document mode compatibility issue, press F12 in IE and change your document mode to highest standard

Comment: I have tried with all document compatibility options and modes.The script is not loading the jQuery,but in separate tab the file is accessible.